# Foursquare venues from a specific area

Tags: python, django, foursquare

I want to retrieve all 4sq venues from a specific area. Now I can get some venues like this:https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74 where ll is my geopoint. I can pass a radius argument, but my area can have any shape. 
For my backend I use Django

Comment: why not sample your shape with several disks of small radii, and query several times ?

Comment: why not use a radius that encompasses entire shape, then test returned results to see if they are inside the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/venues/search now supports querying with rectangles (in addition to circles). Specify "sw" and "ne" params instead of "ll" in your request.

You can also now specify "intent=browse" to get back the best results in an area, not weighted by proximity to your region's center.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html

This still doesn't support arbitrary polygons or do an exhaustive retrieval of venues (it'll return the 50 best for any region) but it should be a step closer to what you're looking for.